# D3.js: Attributes after enter().append() not setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, d3.js, css-selectors

Like most people, I'm struggling with D3's data join mechanics. I have read every article on the subject, good and (mostly) bad. Christian Behrens' [guest-and-chair party analogy](https://medium.com/@c_behrens/enter-update-exit-6cafc6014c36#.7qqvh9xmu) is probably the best, though I warn readers that he neglects us about 2/3 through, beginning with "Now our update() function performs two different sets of actions" -- he doesn't clarify here that, apparently, DOM construction (append/remove) calls are specifically ignored by the update selection, while attribute calls are processed by all three selection types, *despite* all appearing seamlessly in one method chain. (For his part, Mike Bostock's several efforts at explaining data joins and method chaining range from mildly condescending to entirely complicating matters.)

I still have a problem understanding the membrane between data() and enter(), specifically when to save a variable and how calls in a given chain operate on what objects, and also which chain return value my variable saves, and how I should know that (clearly, attr does not affect the variable, but in a chain that includes a series of selects, data, and enters, which is returned?); hence my mild criticism of the otherwise excellent Behrens essay, because it has so much promise there.

Below, I have a force layout (could be any layout) that displays two nodes on startup, and if you click any of the nodes, a third should be added.

```
var graph = {
  "nodes":[ {"name":"1" }, {"name":"2" } ],
  "links":[ {"source":0,"target":1} ]
}

var width = 500, height = 400;

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")

var rect = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("pointer-events", "all");

var container = svg.append("g");

force
  .nodes(graph.nodes)
  .links(graph.links)
  .start();

var link = container.append("g")
  .attr("class", "links")
  .selectAll(".link")
  .data(graph.links)
  .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
  .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

var nodes = container.append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes");

function update() {

  var n = nodes.selectAll(".node").data(graph.nodes);

  ne = n.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })  // sets on initial enter() but not on click
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; }); // sets on initial enter() but not on click

  ne.append("rect")
    .attr("width", "20")
    .attr("height", "20")
    .attr("fill", "red");

    return n;

} // end update()

var node = update();

force.on("tick", function() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
  node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
});

node.on("click", function(d) {
  graph.nodes.push({ "name":"3" });
  update();
}); // end .on("click")
```

I made an update() function to economize, following Behrens. Setting cx and cy works fine initially but not when you click on a node. New nodes stay at [0,0]. I think there must be a problem in the way I manage the arguments and returns on update(). A better way to do this, one that actually works?

Comment: Where do you define `node` and `link` that you're using in the `tick` handler function?

Comment: Hi, Lars. I defined node and link above.

Answer (score 1):

You're just missing two small things. First, you need to restart the force layout so that the node positions are updated, and you need to update `node` which you're using inside the `tick` handler function:

```
node.on("click", function(d) {
  graph.nodes.push({ "name":"3" });
  node = update();
  force.start();
});
```

Complete demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/33xrz7nr).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this on my own with some experimentation; it seems to have had to do with the fact that I needed to put the force.on("tick"...) and node.on("click") functions inside the update() function. If I didn't have the tick processor in there, it would not create a transform for the new node, which appears to conform to what I was seeing. In addition, I must call force.start() again after updating. I will post the working code at my next opportunity: it is on an offline laptop right now.